# Why does torch.cuda.is_available() return True in terminal but False in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

As you can see from the image below, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True` in terminal but `False` in Jupyter notebook. It seems that I am using the same Python.

**In Jupyter notebook:**

```
import torch
```

```
!which python
```

/home/s1612415/miniconda3/envs/test/bin/python

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

False

**In terminal:**

```
(test) w7830$ which python
~/miniconda3/envs/test/bin/python
(test) w7830$ python
Python 3.10.10 (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:45:11) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

[image]

Comment: I think you assumption about using the same python is wrong and nothing you have shown in your question proves otherwise

Comment: @talonmies `which python` returns the same path?

Comment: But `which python` is doing the exact same thing that you do from the command line. It’s says nothing about the interpreter and libraries being used within the notebook kernel

Comment: @talonmies What would prove they are using the same Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.python_version for example

Comment: @talonmies Both return `'3.10.10'`. You can also see in my screenshot that they are both using 3.10.10.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in local installation on Windows and resolved by following these steps:

1. Installed the cudatoolkit from [nvidia’s site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
2. Then followed the post installation steps like setting the path variable from
   [installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

First, try to run the command `print(torch.cuda.is_available())` in cmd to see what the result is.

Run cmd then type python:

```
python
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Because it is possible that you have cuda installed and it works correctly, but in `JypyterLab` and base(root) environment, this command returns `False`, in this case, try to add `nb_conda_kernels` in active `Conda` env by running the following command.

We should first install `nb_conda_kernels` in active `Conda` env

Or run this command:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name notebook_env --display-name "Python (notebook_env)"
```

If you want to go through the steps step by step, check the link below:

[Tutorial: CUDA, cuDNN, Anaconda, Jupyter, PyTorch Installation](https://sh-tsang.medium.com/tutorial-cuda-cudnn-anaconda-jupyter-pytorch-installation-in-windows-10-96b2a2f0ac57)